# Xamarin form: Can we separate the datatemplate with Views or App.xaml or Content Page

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, datatemplate

Normally I define the datatemplate either inside the App.xaml, ContentPage.xaml or View.xaml level. Is it possible to define a datatemplate in a separate xaml file so I can assign a datatemplate to the views in code

```
if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone)
                childListView.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["phoneSignInTemplate"];
            else if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet)
                childListView.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["tabletSignInTemplate"];
```

If I place too many datatemplate in App.xaml or ContentPage or Views level. I worried about will it affect the performance when loading the pages.

Comment: You might be interested in MergedDictionaries https://xamarinhelp.com/merged-dictionaries-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 0):

You can generate new ViewCells in xaml and use them as DataTemplates:

MyTextViewCell.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ViewCell 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="XFTests.MyTextViewCell">
    <ViewCell.View>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label
                Text="Not a phone" />
            <Label Text="{Binding .}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ViewCell.View>
</ViewCell>
```

MyTextViewCellPhone.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ViewCell 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="XFTests.MyTextViewCellPhone">
    <ViewCell.View>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label
                Text="Phone" />
            <Label Text="{Binding .}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ViewCell.View>
</ViewCell>
```

Then assign the one you need to item template.

```
ListView listView = new ListView
{
    ItemsSource = new string[] { "Max", "John" }
};

if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone)
    listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(MyTextViewCellPhone));
else
     listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(MyTextViewCell));
```